# Probability calculation and comparison in Simulated Annealing

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, search, optimization, simulated-annealing

I just realized I made a mistake in an algorithm I wrote years ago.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/298209081/figure/fig7/AS:341632911200275@1458463041655/Flowchart-of-simulated-annealing-algorithm.png

Instead of r < p in this flow, what I did was checking if p <= r. Honestly, I cannot put my mind together to decide if this is a huge mistake or not.

```
delta = old state - new state
P = exp(delta / T) * 100
if(delta > 0 or P <= random(100))
{
 accept(new state)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P` becomes smaller and smaller as the temperature rises. When you check for `r < p` it becomes ***increasingly unlikely*** that your search will switch from the current state to a worse new state. This is the idea of Simulated Annealing.

You check for `p <= r`, which makes it ***increasingly likely*** that your search will switch to a worse state in the end and less likely at the beginning. I assume you will get very mixed results with this as you are doing exploitation first and exploration later.